# Installing rails app on Linux gives google maps api errors in javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, deployment, passenger

I have an app written in ruby on rails which is running fine on my Mac.  However when I install the app on Linux via Passanger the Google maps on the page don't work and I get a javascript error.  Is there anything that needs to be done so external javascripts will run?

[image]

The error is in the file geometry.js from google maps:

[image]

The only difference between firebug running from local computer and the linux box is I get the list of js files in the screenshot above in different order although the code is exactly the same.

If I run the rails probram on WEBrick on the linux machine I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was including all the javascript files instead of using just :default.  That solved the problem.